# Periodic REST API calls using Azure components

Tags: rest, api, azure, job-scheduling

I would like to make a periodically scheduled sequence of REST API call to a 3rd party service, and send the result to an Azure Event hub or Azure SQL. An example would be to fetch the weather for yesterday for x locations (requiring x API calls).

So far I have looked at :
* a virtual machine with some python code, using some scheduler on that machine. That works, but us not the most elegant way
* using Azure scheduler (not OK, since it does not seem possible to dynamically build up the API call, e.g. using date-1 as a parameter)
* data factory : seems overkill, and not really purposed to do this

What would be the recommended way to do this ?

Comment: azure function apps is a good choice for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up using an Azure function for this, which can be triggered by an REST call through azure scheduler

As my function code was in python, it took a while to find how to do it, but this was a great start :

https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/docs/create-function-app-in-azure-portal.md

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, i recommend to use Azure Web Job to achieve it.

WebJobs is a feature of Azure App Service that enables us to run a program or script in the same context as a web app, API app, or mobile app.

We can use Scheduled triggered WebJobs to call REST API periodically.

More information about WebJobs we can refer to: [Run Background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs)

Below screenshot shows how to create a Scheduled triggered WebJob which will run periodically every 20 minutes.

[image]

To create it, we just need to upload a compressed file of the .exe in the .zip format, then we can run this .exe program periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly the same through Azure Logic Apps.

Logic Apps can be triggered on a schedule, or through HTTP trigger.

In order to have a dynamic system (e.g. different locations), I stored the locations in an Azure table. The logic app will fetch the locations from the Azure table, and dynamically build the API calls, and send the result to an event hub.

The date-1 can easily be set as a parameter at execution time.

Only a very limited amount of coding required